# What's causing this syntax error?

Tags: python

FEEL FREE TO FLAG THIS POST SINEC IT WAS CAUSED BY A TYPO....APOLOGIES

I cannot figure out for the life of me why this try and except statement is return a syntax error. Is it something earlier in the code / a typo?

```
import csv

# This function takes a tab-delim csv and merges the ones with the same name but different phone / email / websites.
def merge_duplicates(sheet):

    with(open(sheet, 'rU')) as f:

        mysheet = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = '\t')    
        mysheet_list = list(mysheet)

        for rowvalue, row in enumerate(mysheet_list):
            print rowvalue, row

            try:
                if row['name'] == mysheet_list[rowvalue+1]['name']:
                    if row['email'] != mysheet_list[rowvalue+1]['email']:
                        row['alt_email'] = mysheet_list[rowvalue+1['email']
#                     if row['website'] != mysheet_list[rowvalue+1]['website']:
#                         row['alt_website'] != mysheet_list[rowvalue+1]['website']
            except IndexError:
                print("We're at the end now") 

merge_duplicates('ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt')
```

If it helps, I've provided a link, [HERE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AdpUpb788T-Zp0nKD9C3CZcv3Yq9y0dm__Kq9kulQAM/edit?usp=sharing) to the example spreadsheet.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please post the full stack trace that comes with the error.

Comment: See below for the answer.  The stack trace produced by Python should have given you the precise line number and most syntax highlighting editors would similarly have pointed out the offending line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing `]` here:

```
mysheet_list[rowvalue+1['email']
                       ^
                       |
```

it should be:

```
mysheet_list[rowvalue+1]['email']
```

Answer (score 2):

In `row['alt_email'] = mysheet_list[rowvalue+1['email']` You are missing a `]`.

Fixed:

`row['alt_email'] = mysheet_list[rowvalue+1['email']]`

Comment: Your `fix` is wrong, if `rowvalue+1` returns a number then `4['email']` is going to raise an error again. `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`